# Prolog, listing/1, Built-in System Predicates, SWI-Prolog 7.4.2

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to get the definitions for a few built-in predicates using SWI-Prolog 7.4.2.  Specifically, `split_string/4`.

`explain/1` returns:

``` system:split_string/4 is a built-in predicate
        Summary: ``Break a string into substrings''
true. ```

`listing/1` returns:

`Foreign: system:split_string/4
true.`

I've checked the System.pl file, but I cannot seem to find the definition.  Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWI-Prolog is C based. Look for *.c in [github](https://github.com/swi-prolog), more specifically at [this source](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/master/src/pl-string.c#L281).